# Simulating a Windows 8 Store apps purchase

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, in-app-purchase

I am trying to put together code that simulates purchases for a Windows 8 (Store) app.

The code is pretty simple and uses the Windows API:

```
var result = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("product", true);

// this is still false...
var active = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["product"].IsActive;
```

The first call opens up the dialog that allows me to simulate the return code from the purchase.

Even when i select S_OK, the next line still checks to see if the license is active and returns false.

What is wrong here?

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999604/windows-8-store-app-how-do-i-test-in-app-purchase

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you updating the `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` file? You have to do that otherwise the purchase will never be set to active. You don't need to call `RequestAppPurchaseAsync...` only the `requestProductPurchaseAsync.` Do this...

Run your app in debug mode breaking anywhere
Open QuickWatch (SHIFT + F9) and enter Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.roamingFolder.path and copy the value (mine was `C:\Users\jerfost\AppData\Local\Packages\{package name}\LocalState`
Browse to that location and open the Microsoft\Windows Store\ApiData directory
Open the `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` file in a text editor
Change `CurrentApp/LicenseInformation/App/IsTrial` to false
Change `CurrentApp/ListingInformation/Product/MarketData/Name` to your unique product name
That should do it. Hope that helps.

Comment: what about ProductId?
You do have to change the ProductId to your unique product name, too, don't you?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to manually edit the XML everytime, CurrentAppSimulator does it automatically.

Just check your setting in the WindowsStoreProxy.xml and ensure that 'IsTrial' is set 'false'-

```
<LicenseInformation>
    <App>
        <IsActive>true</IsActive>
        <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
    </App>
    <Product ProductId="1">
        <IsActive>false</IsActive>
    </Product>
</LicenseInformation>
```

*Remember - In-app purchases does not work in Trial version of the app.*