# LicenseInformation IsTrial is always true, even after buying the app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have published an app in Windows store, but it's hidden for the moment, so I could test.

There is a Trial in the app, giving you access to some level. I didn't put any time limit. When you buy the game, you should have access to all the levels. But the "IsTrial" is always true.

```
private static LicenseInformation _licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;

public static bool IsLevelEnabled(LevelViewModel level)
{
#if DEBUG
  return true;
#else
  if (_licenseInformation.IsActive)
  {
    if (_licenseInformation.IsTrial) //Problem, always true
    {
      if ([...])//some logic to check is level is enabled in Trial.
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else //Should go here when you buy the app.
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
#endif
}
```

My code is base on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn532253(v=win.10).aspx.

Thanks

**Edit**

Someone else bought my app on the store, don't think he tried the trial. Everything is fine for him. He had access to all levels. And I'm still stuck in trial.

Comment: My crystal ball says that your forgot to [turn simulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241881/simulating-a-windows-8-store-apps-purchase) off.

Comment: I uninstall everything and I tried a fresh install from the store. I didn't touch the WindowsStoreProxy.xml, and i'm not using the CurrentAppSimulator. Do I need to write the WindowsStoreProxy.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on other computers and it was fine, so it's a problem with my account on one computer.

So the code is ok.

I could change the code like Nasser said and refresh the license each time, but it was not necessary for me.

Still have the problem on one computer. Put I don't think i'll find the anwser in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your app is associated with your dev account .

And are you running your app in Debug Mode ? while you have the `#if DEBUG ..` for returning true if it's running in Debug mode !

And try to make a prop method for that :

```
private bool IsTrial()
    {
        var li = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
        if (li.IsActive)
        {
            return li.IsTrial;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The app is associated. I tried it with the online version of it, (I also bought the app), also tried with Visual Studio in release. Changing the license for a local variable doesn't seem to help. IsActive is always true, trial is also always true.